# Piping two server calls

Tags: scripts, sh

I am trying to pipe two server runs (one using yarn, one using phoenix/elixir). My code:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start;
source env/local.env;
iex -S mix phx.server|
cd front-end;
yarn start:dev-ng;
```

However, I bump into all sorts of errors. My question is how to best set this up. Is there a way to effectively pipe this or do I have to do this in two separate shell scripts (that would be cumbersome)?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, piping produces text output from a command or sequence of commands, and sends to consumer - another sequence of commands. So you could do something like `{ echo foo; echo bar; } | { grep foo; grep bar;  }` if you see what I did there. As for actual commands, piping to `cd` is kinda pointless - `cd` doesn't consume stdin stream. So if you need to execute `yarn` in `front-end` directory, do that `cd` command before piping.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the curly brackets: :-}

Comment: Alright, I'll convert my comment into a proper answer, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, piping produces text output from a command or sequence of commands, and sends to consumer - another sequence of commands. So you could do something like `{ echo foo; echo bar; } | { grep foo; grep bar; }` if you see what I did there.

As for actual commands, piping to `cd` is kinda pointless - `cd` doesn't consume stdin stream. So if you need to execute `yarn` in the `front-end` directory, do that `cd` command before piping.